# participial construction

Tags: participle-clauses

> Longer life spans mean more people, worsening food and housing supply difficulties.

Can I change the sentence above to the sentence below?

> Longer life spans mean more people, and worsen food and housing supply difficulties.

Comment: No, because "worsen" is a verb so it cannot modify the noun phrase "food and housing supply difficulties". (Verbs do not normally modify nouns).

Comment: Disagreeing with @BillJ: Yes, you can use *mean* and *worsen* as parallel verbs in this way.